# vb .net 2012 datepicker uppercase MAY month turns into 5AY

Tags: vb.net

I used this code to make month in uppercase form, the problem is that the month of May turns into 5AY

```
DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = Strings.UCase(Format(DateTimePicker1.Value, "ddMMMyyyy"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realising that you were trying to actually use the month name as literal characters in your format specifier, I knew that you just had to escape those special characters.  Normally, date format specifiers use the "\" character to escape but the `DateTimePicker.CustomFormat` property specifically requires you to wrap escaped characters in single quotes.  I just tested this and it worked as expected:

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
    DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = $"dd'{DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MMM").ToUpper()}'yyyy"
End Sub
```

If you're using an older version of VB that doesn't support string interpolation, this will do the same thing:

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
    DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = String.Format("dd'{0}'yyyy", DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MMM").ToUpper())
End Sub
```

There's no need to set the `Format` property in code as it won't change.  Just set it once in the designer.  You'll probably want to execute that same code on `Load` because there's no `ValueChanged` event when the `DateTimePicker` takes on the current date/time by default.

Comment: By the way, if you were going to use that incorrect code, why write it like you're using VB6?  `Strings.UCase(Format(DateTimePicker1.Value, "ddMMMyyyy"))` would be better written `DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("ddMMMyyyy").ToUpper()`.

Comment: thanks, but all of the months display was correct, except for March, May, September, November, and December

Comment: OK, I think I see what's going on now.  You're taking the date as it is and using that as a format specifier, in which case the letters in the month name are actually interpreted as literal characters.  The reason that some are not working is that they are special characters.  For example, "A" and "Y" have no special meaning so they are displayed as themselves.  "M" is the format specifier for the number of the month, so that's why you see "5" instead of "M".  Let me fiddle a bit and I'll edit my answer.